# auto load more items with android

Tags: android, json, android-listview

i have this code which bring JSON data from the website and it's working very fine

whai i want to do is, load 10 items and when the user scroll to the bottom it loads another 10 items ...etc until the items finished

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;

    //Feeds URL - Your Website URL where you uploaded the admin panel
    private String URL_FEED = "http://EXAMPLE.COM";


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        //Getting feeds from the website into listview 
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);


    }

    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    ///Menus functions
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();

        switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            session.logoutUser();
            break;
        case R.id.myProfile:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.addPhoto:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, UploadPhoto.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```